# Cannot update ECS Fargate service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, blue-green-deployment

I am running an ECS Fargate service with `deploymentController` as `CODE_DEPLOY`.
Now, when I `--force-new-deployment` using aws cli.

**AWS CLI Command**

`aws ecs update-service --cluster my-cluster --service my-service --force-new-deployment`

I get following error.
`An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the UpdateService operation: Cannot force a new deployment on services with a CODE_DEPLOY deployment controller. Use AWS CodeDeploy to trigger a new deployment.`

Even in the docs it's not mentioned regariding teh update scenarios https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html
Is there any workaround this?

Comment: Why aren't you using codedeploy to do this, since that's what you set up for deployments?

Comment: @RobertHafner True. So in the new ECS console `CODEDEPLOY` is not supported. Also, when I use classic console, we can force deploy from the UI and it triggers deployment in codedeploy. I don't get why CLI doesn't support force deployment, because that's what I was under the impression with.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `CodeDeploy` to manage deployments and not `Amazon ECS`.
In the `AWS Classic Console`, the forced deployment option uses `Code Deploy` behind the scenes 
At the moment ecs-cli does not support the forced deployment feature for `Code Deploy` deployment controller

Comment: But why the classic console triggers the code deploy on update of the service and not cli ?

Comment: The classic console uses CodeDeploy behind the scenes